# extract string between two strings where the second string may or may not exist

Tags: java, mysql, regex, string

I want to parse a sql query in java. its a part of my project. 
Now I need to extract the arguments in the 'from' clause. Since they exist between 'from' and 'where' clauses i used the following Pattern for matching,

```
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("from" + "(.*?)" + "(where)?");
```

Since the where clause may or may not exist in a query i used a '?' after where. But im not getting the expected 'from' arguments when i use a query like

```
     select * from student;
```

I am not really familiar with regex . Please help

Comment: Try either of these: `\\bfrom([^w]*(?:w(?!here\\b)[^w]*)*)` or `(?s)\\bfrom((?:(?!\\bwhere\\b).)*)`.

Comment: @stribizhev  thanks it works . i used this `(?s)\\bfrom((?:(?!\\bwhere\\b).)*)` .. but it extracts along with semicolon as "student;" . How to ignore semicolon and please tell me how this regex works , what do those characters denote?

Comment: Don't you think the answer below is what you need?

Comment: You can use [`(?s)\\bfrom((?:(?!\\bwhere\\b).)*);`](https://regex101.com/r/nI9yH4/1) if the `;` is always at the end as the value you need is in Group 1. The `(?:(?!\\bwhere\\b).)*` construct is called *tempered greedy token*. This solution is not very efficient, so only use it if you cannot use anything else.

Answer (score 0):

**Tip : Why not just `substring` it?**

```
/*
Regex explanation:
  'from'    - when found `from` char sequence
  '\\s*'    - skip whitespace
  '(.*?)'   - capture some chars in `non-greedy` mode
  '('       - and then
    'where' - must be `where` char sequence
    '|;'    - or a semicolon
    '|$'    - or end of matching string
  ')'  
*/
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("from\\s*(.*?)(where|;|$)");

static String extract1(String query) {

  String tables = null;

  Matcher m = p.matcher(query);
  if (m.find())
    tables = m.group(1).trim();

  return tables;
}

static String extract2(String query) {
  String term = query.toLowerCase();
  int from = term.indexOf("from");
  if (from < 0)
    return null;

  int to = term.indexOf("where");
  if (to < 0) {
    to = term.length();
    while (term.charAt(to - 1) == ';')
      to--;
  }

  return query.substring(from + 4, to).trim();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String query1 = "select * from table as t";
  String query2 = "select * from table as t;";
  String query3 = "select * from table as u where a = b";
  String query4 = "select * from table as u where a = b;";

  String t1, t2;

  t1 = extract1(query1);
  t2 = extract2(query1);
  System.out.printf("\"%s\":\n  %s\n  %s\n\n", query1, t1, t2);

  t1 = extract1(query2);
  t2 = extract2(query2);
  System.out.printf("\"%s\":\n  %s\n  %s\n\n", query2, t1, t2);

  t1 = extract1(query3);
  t2 = extract2(query3);
  System.out.printf("\"%s\":\n  %s\n  %s\n\n", query3, t1, t2);

  t1 = extract1(query4);
  t2 = extract2(query4);
  System.out.printf("\"%s\":\n  %s\n  %s\n\n", query4, t1, t2);
}
```

Results:

```
"select * from table as t":
  table as t
  table as t

"select * from table as t;":
  table as t
  table as t

"select * from table as u where a = b":
  table as u
  table as u

"select * from table as u where a = b;":
  table as u
  table as u
```

Comment: wow thanks. this substring approach is really helpful. thank you @ankhzet

Comment: I'm a little confused: where does the "4" in "return query.substring(from + 4, to).trim();" come from?

Comment: `term.indexOf("from")` returns first position, at which `from` substring begins. But we want only portion of query `after` that `from` keyword, so we skippin' it when retriving `substring(to + 4, ...)`, or there 'd be `from table as u` as result. `4` is just length of skipped (`from`) portion.